# Passing generic parameters into MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, generics

I'm building an MVC controller, which will accept a JSON object, but I want to make the type it accepts generic. Can I do this?

```
public class RecognitionData<T> 
{
    DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    string Line1 { get; set; }
    string Line2 { get; set; }
    string Locality { get; set; }
    string Country { get; set; }
    string Postcode { get; set; }
}

public class AddressController : Controller
{
    public string Save(RecognitionData<Address> result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to do post the data as JSON, while I can see the "result" field in Request["result"] as a string, the "result" parameter is blank.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487005/asp-net-mvc-model-binder-for-generic-type

Answer (score 5):

Try to make the properties in your model public.

Comment: Doh. I couldn't post my exact code so put an example of what I was trying to do. Missed making them public out of my example :)

Comment: :) but I think the issue still not in generic model. Try to create not generic version of RecognitionData { public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public Address Value { get; set; } } and specify this as argument of the action. And if it will work the problem really in current model, otherwise - not