# Creating a static model from dynamic data in a WebApi model binder

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have my `POST` method which I use to trigger the sending of an email

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(IEmail model)
{
    SendAnEmailPlease(model);
}
```

I have many types of email to send so I abstract away to an interface so I only need one post method

```
 config.BindParameter(typeof(IEmail), new EmailModelBinder());
```

I have my model binder which gets hit fine

```
public class EmailModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(
        HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
    {
        // Logic here           

        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the logic for turning the `bindingContext.PropertyMetadata` into one of my email POCOs

```
public IDictionary<string, ModelMetadata> PropertyMetadata { get; }
```

In the PropertyMetadata I'm passing the object type as a string which I think I could use to create a class with the `Activator.CreateInstance` method.

```
eg: EmailType = MyProject.Models.Email.AccountVerificationEmail
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

---

**Related questions**

- [ASP.NET Web API Model Binder for Generic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905295/asp-net-web-api-model-binder-for-generic-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, might be useful to someone else out there.

```
public class EmailModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(
        HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string body = actionContext.Request.Content
                       .ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Dictionary<string, string> values = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(body);

        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(IEmail).Assembly.FullName, 
            values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ObjectType").Value
            ).Unwrap();

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(body, entity);

        bindingContext.Model = (IEmail)entity;

        return true;
    }
}
```